# Argument function along circle

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

> Let $0<r<a$. Determine a continuous argument function along the path $\alpha :[0,2\pi]\to \mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ with $\alpha(t)=a+re^{it}$.

---

I thought this sketch describes the situation an my idea of the solution:
[image]

The aim is to determine the argument function called $\varphi(t)$ in this picture. Obviously the hyptothenuse is the radius $r$. One can get $\varphi(t)$ with - I think - quite easy trigonometric equations, but I can't see the height of the triangle. Any hints?
Thank you!

Comment: Hint : The height of the triangle is $r \sin t$ ... answer verification on request ...

Comment: Thank you @DonaldSplutterwit. I got this: $$\varphi(t)=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{r\sin(t)}{\alpha(t)}\right)$$

Comment: oooh ... not quite ... is it inverse sin ?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit I thought so, yes. Because $\sin(\varphi(t))=\frac{r\sin(t)}{\alpha(t)}$?

Comment: $ \mid \alpha(t) \mid$ ... $ \alpha $ is a complex quantity ? & this could be simplified further.

Comment: So the inverse sin is not correct? And yeah, of course $\vert\alpha(t)\vert$ sorry.

Comment: $ \varphi = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{r \sin t}{a+ r \cos(t) } \right)$ is what I have written in my note book.
But your $ \varphi = \sin^{-1} \left( \frac{r \sin t}{\sqrt{a^2+ 2ar \cos(t)+r^2} } \right)$ will do though.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Quite easy, thank you for your effort! But is this the final argument function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conider the points $z_1,z_2$  on the circle such that the line thru $0,z_1$ and the line thru $0,z_2$ are tangent to the circle. There exist real $t_1,t_2$ with $t_1<t_2<t_1+\pi$ with $z_j=a+re^{it_j}$ for $j\in \{1,2\}.$ For every $p$ on the circle there is a unique $f(p)\in [t_1,t_2]$ such that $p=|p|e^{if(p)}.$  We may define the arg of $p$ as $f(p).$

Let $a=|a|e^{iu}$ with $u\in [0,2\pi).$ Let $v= cos^{-1}(r/|a|)\in (0,\pi /2).$ We may take $t_1= u-v-\pi$ and $t_2=u+v-\pi.$